# Youtube/SoundCloud video open in new tab when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, soundcloud

I am trying to add to my Tumblr page a way for when a youtube video or a SoundClouds is clicked, it shall open into another window. I am unable to figure out how to do this. 
Here is a example of them code I am using for SoundCloud

```
<a href="{text:Link Two}" target="_blank"class="links">{text:Link Two Title}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: Where is the example? Have you done any research because I'm sure this question has been asked many times before "how to open external window"

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-best-code-is-no-code-at-all/

Comment: XD didn't click enter

Comment: This equation has but I couldn't find anything for soundcloud or youtube

Comment: So you have an iframe, what have you tried so far? Display your attempts as this is very little to work with.

Comment: If you know this question has been asked before, why don't you read the existing answer, learn it, understand how to change it to fit your needs? Answers given are for people to learn from and understand, not a copy/paste into the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to open in another window, why don't you link to it instead of using an `iframe`? Using a `iframe` is for when you want it ***specifically*** within an ***area*** of the same window.

Try something like this:

```
<a href="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/188684529&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true" target="_blank"></a>
```

Setting the `target` attribute to `_blank` should open the link in a new window.

Comment: Please upvote/mark as correct if this answer has solved your problem.

Comment: <a href="{text:Link Two}" target="_blank"class="links">{text:Link Two Title}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I tried it like this but it did not work (link two is the soundcloud link) any ideas?

Comment: I suggest writing the link out as written here. Don't use magic.

Answer (score 0):

Go for an anchor tag i.e.`<a>`

This should solve the issue.

See the code below:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/188684529&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true" target="_blank">Sound Cloud</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps